# Why is Landscape so slow?

Tags: server, landscape, client

I have installed a Landscape-server 15.01 for personal use on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server, i have connected 4 clients so far but everything is going extremely slow.

it can take upto 5-10 minutes to reboot one of the clients, if i am doing it manually it will take about 30-40 sec.

and update packages can take up to 30 min ?

Can this really be true? or is tehre a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot and shutdown activities are delayed by 5 minutes on the client side on purpose. If there is someone logged in at the console, he/she will have 5min to save his/her work, or cancel the reboot/shutdown.

About package updates taking 30min, that could depend on a lot of factors:

- your bandwidth from the client to the ubuntu archive
- if this happened right after a client registered with the server. There is an initial delay while package data is synchronized between server and client. It's usually a few minutes, but can be up to 3h if it's an ubuntu release that the server has seen for the first time and for which there are no hash-id files (check /var/lib/landscape/ or something like that for a hash-id directory, I don't remember the exact name from memory).
- also for the above case, if the package activity happened while that sync was going on, the client will log something about unknown hash-ids in /var/log/landscape/package-reporter.log or package-changer.log. That has a timeout of 2h IIRC, to give time for the client to run apt-get update on its own (package reporter interval configuration sets that).

Hope this helps.